# How to create a random sequence excepting a set of given values

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, random

I am using numpy and i want to generate an array of size `n` with random integers from `a` to `b` [upper bound exclusive] that are not in the array `arr` (if it helps, all values in `arr` are unique). I want the probability to be distributed uniformly among the other possible values. I am aware I can do it in this way:

```py
randlist = np.random.randint(a, b, n)
while np.intersect1d(randlist, arr).size > 0:
    randlist = np.random.randint(a, b, n)
```

But this seems really inefficent. What would be the fastest way to do this?

Comment: Try keeping the excluded elements in a set instead.

Comment: How would that help? @AlexHall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest vectorized way would be with `np.setdiff1d` + `np.random.choice` -

```
c = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(a,b),arr)
out = np.random.choice(c,n)
```

Another way with `masking` -

```
mask = np.ones(b-a,dtype=bool)
mask[arr-a] = 0
idx = np.flatnonzero(mask)+a
out = idx[np.random.randint(0,len(idx),n)]
```

Comment: Which method would be faster?

Comment: @ѕняєєѕιиgнι Would depend a lot on your a,b and arr values and their lengths. So, can you test out with your dataset?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `out = a + idx ...`?